# Spring Boot OAuth2 errors after invalidating session and accessing data from Resource Server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

My architecture consists of three applications:

- Authorization Server (10.10.1.1:8080)
- Client A (10.10.3.3:8084)
- Client B (10.10.2.2:8089)

Both Client A and B are serving static Angular files. Both clients are "communicating" with each other - it is possible to navigate from the first one to another one and back as well (through normal `window.location.replace`).

Everything works great instead of one specific situation.

1. I'm logging into Client A application (through Authorization server redirect).
2. I'm opening Client B - user is properly authenticated based on Client A.
3. I'm coming back to Client A - user is still authenticated. (I can repeat steps 2 and 3 endlessly)
4. I'm logging out from Client A.
5. I'm logging in again into Client A with the same or different user.
6. I'm opening Client B and getting blank page due to some network issues.

After page refresh everything works fine (`JSESSIONID` is changing in the browser and user is properly authenticated).
I've tried couple different approaches and configurations using session invalidation. Session is properly invalidated but then it is not created again (user is changing to anonymous instead of being properly taken from Client A).
Then follows redirect to authorization server, which isn't available for some reason.

The problem here is that normal flow after redirect (step 2) is:

1. Redirect to `10.10.2.2:8089/home-page`
2. `/home-page` gets `302 REDIRECT` in network tab to `/login`
3. `/login` redirects to `10.10.1.1:8080/oauth/authorize`
4. then it redirects back to `/home-page` with status `200 OK`.

Error flow after redirect (step 6) is:

1. Redirect to `10.10.2.2:8089/home-page`
2. `/home-page` gets `200 OK` in network tab
3. application loads the page and it makes request for user data (`/api/user`) which gets `401`
4. the entire redirect cycle takes place and ends with unability to redirect to `10.10.1.1:8080/oauth/authorize`
5. after page refresh everything works fine.

I've tried:

- couple different approaches and configurations in security (both on Client A and Client B)
- allowing all origins in `CorsFilter` (for testing purposes - even that didn't help)
- adding another cookie through `server.servlet.cookie.name` and erasing it by `deleteCookies()` or proper handler
- adding `maximumSessions(2)` for tests purposes - even that didn't help

At last I made some tricky solution. I made request to Client B before redirect to Client A. It removed `JSESSIONID` through `HttpServletResponse`. It helped, but only when I'm working on one browser tab.
If I have two tabs opened (one with Client A and one with Client B) after doing step 5 and 6 and refreshing the page on Client B, problem still persists (because I didn't erase `JSESSIONID` from the browser).

I don't know if I understand this problem properly (that `JSESSIONID` is problematic in the browser), so correct me if I'm wrong. Also - I don't know how to erase this cookie or allow OAuth2 Filters to automatically create new one and invalidate the session in proper way.
Can anybody help me with this problem and show what I'm doing wrong here?

**Client A - Security Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public OAuth2RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate(final OAuth2ClientContext context,
                                                 final OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails details) {
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(details, context);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .formLogin()
                .and()
                    .logout().clearAuthentication(true)
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    // .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    // .logoutSuccessHandler((httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, authentication) -> {httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);})
                    .addLogoutHandler(new ProperCookieClearingLogoutHandler("JSESSIONID"))
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/index.html", "/main.html", "/login", "/resources/**", ...)
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
    }
}
```

**Client B - Security Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public OAuth2RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate(final OAuth2ClientContext context,
                                                 final OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails details) {
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(details, context);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .logout().clearAuthentication(true)
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    // .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    // .logoutSuccessHandler((httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, authentication) -> {httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);})
                    .addLogoutHandler(new ProperCookieClearingLogoutHandler("JSESSIONID"))
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/index.html", "/main.html", "/resources/**", "/login/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
    }
}
```

**Authorization Server - Security Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login")
                .permitAll().and()
                .formLogin().failureHandler(new FailureAuthenticationHandler())
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .and().requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/login")
                .antMatchers("/oauth/authorize")
                .antMatchers("/oauth/confirm_access")
                .and()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().sessionManagement().maximumSessions(-1).expiredUrl("/...").sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
    }

    @Bean
    SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    ... authentication providers ...


    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    CustomTokenStore customTokenStore;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
         clients.inMemory().withClient("x").secret("x")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("x").autoApprove(true).scopes("x");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints.tokenStore(customTokenStore).authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) {
        oauthServer.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
    }
}
```

Full log from Client B:
https://pastebin.com/aVc5AXcx

Thank you in advance.

**24.10.2020 - TOPIC EDIT**

After digging deeper and doing some research I probably found a core of the problem, but I don't know how to solve it yet.

**First problem**

There are two OAuth2 clients (annoted with `@EnableOAuth2Sso`) that share the same session and user data, but they don't know about each other openly (and about each other login/logout state).

1. I'm working on Client B and triggering logout call on that specific client.
2. Then I'm redirecting to authorization server login page with specific logout params.
3. I'm making logout call to authorization server on `POST` method and `/logout` path.
4. After successfull user logout I'm doing `window.location.replace` to Client A, which gets unauthorized error in network tab (401):

```
WWW-Authenticate header: Bearer realm="oauth2-resource", error="invalid_token", error_description="Invalid access token: 27ef8abe-e8e5-4d07-aaf4-a82a8757614e"
```

And in console of Client A I get:

```
UserInfoTokenServices: Could not fetch user details: class org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.UserRedirectRequiredException, A redirect is required to get the users approval.
```

**Second problem**

Similiar situation is in the base problem stated in this topic. After relogin on Client A and page refresh on Client B, it has some session/token in cache and think that user is still authenticated in that client. It returns status `200 OK` in HTML routing path (f.e. `/home-page`), but gets unauthorized on first request to API and giving the same invalid_token header:

```
WWW-Authenticate header: Bearer realm="oauth2-resource", error="invalid_token", error_description="Invalid access token: 4026cf9f-8081-4870-b9bf-6e6ff89d4ded" (401)
```

And in Resource Server I get:

```
Unable to obtain a new access token for resource 'null'. The provider manager is not configured to support it.
```

Both clients have the same configuration in properties

```
security.oauth2.client.client-id=x
security.oauth2.client.client-secret=y
security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri=http://${auhorization.server.url}/oauth/authorize
security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri=http://${auhorization.server.url}/oauth/token
security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri=http://${resource.server.url}/user
```

**Conclusion**

I've tried adding csrfHeaderFilter and OAuth2ClientContextFilter from this topic, but it didn't help.
https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/issues/76

So the question is how to handle logout / refresh session and user context in another client after logout from the second one (and authorization server)? I don't know if I'm getting this process right, but I'm still anylizing what's going on here...

Can anybody show me some solution?

Comment: Is it possible to make Github repository? The stated problem is a bit overwhelm for me to understand. Based on your log, I found "Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point". It seems that you are not saving the cookie properly after the user B logged-in. I suggest you can double check in your server whether you handle the cookie for user B properly or not.

Comment: @incubus8 It will be difficult to share this part of my project with others, but I will try to send you something in the coming days.